# Queue filling up while listening to apache nifi from kafka and running python script

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm listening to kafka topic using `consumekafka` in apache nifi. I am running a python script using `executestreamcommand` with the data coming from here. The kafka topic I'm listening to for pro-process happens in an infinite loop in the for loop. That's why the data passing through the queue never ends. queue is filling up. How do I solve this?

Nifi interface

[image: 1]

Python loop
[image: 2]

I thought of a solution. I can put a break at the end of the loop. But too much data is coming. constantly open and close the program slows down?

EDIT : Typing "break" doesn't work, I guess because the data comes too fast, turn it off and on and on it stays very slow.

Comment: I had same issue, I needed data near real time. So I implemented micro-batch before python script and It resolved the issue. or you can create your own processor in nifi.

Comment: 1) Show code, not images 2) Your Python code isn't valid. There's no `data` variable defined

Comment: @MrugeshKadia In fact, the situation is as follows, I have just started working in this field, I am still a student. "you can create your own processor in nifi." Can you explain a little what exactly this means?

Comment: Nifi is written in Java. You write code to create a new box (processor) you can configure in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put a loop in the Python code. Ensure your flow file passes one record to the Python function. Have it return one event. Then forward that to `ProduceKafka` **Nifi** processor rather than needing to install any `kafka-python` dependency

Also, I've not benchmarked it, but I suspect using a Groovy processor, or your own custom Java one, would be faster than starting a Python process

Comment: so I won't be accessing kafka in python. I will reach kafka from nifi and send data from nifi again, right? So how can I show the process outputs to python and do the pre-process steps? thank you for the answer

Comment: You're already running ExecuteStreamCommand and running python code. I'm saying to print/return output from that, and forward to Nifi ProduceKafka processor. Don't use `producer.send` in Python code